# How can I sort concat_ws(';',collect_set(name)) result in hive?

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, concatenation, hiveql

How can I sort result of this query alphabetically?

```
select b6.S_Architect as S_Architect 
  from applications a
       left outer join
       (select id,concat_ws(';' , collect_set(name)) as S_Architect 
          from solution_architect
         group by parentcontentid
       ) b6 on a.id = b6.Id;
```

Expected result

```
Andy;Bravo;Cindy;David
```

Actual result

```
Cindy;Bravo;David;Andy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sort_array](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-CollectionFunctions):

```
select concat_ws('\073',sort_array(collect_set(name))) from (select stack(4,'Cindy','Bravo','David','Andy') as name) s;
```

Returns:

```
OK
Andy;Bravo;Cindy;David
```